# Effects of v-show and v-if on first contentful paint (FCP)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I was wondering if there is any difference in using v-show and v-if, on First Contentful Paint(FCP). As v-show renders all elements and just controls them by styles, in terms of visibility, I consider It can have consequences on FCP. so, v-if can be a better choice in terms of FCP optimization. that's how I think about it and I am not sure whether that sounds logical. can someone clarify this please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I get you right, As you said v-show handles elements with CSS displays, and v-if removes or add elements. When your page initiates v-show could show for a moment if it's false but v-if cannot be shown (if it's false) when your page initiates. It means when a v-if is false It will not be shown at all even in the console.

Comment: @NiazEstefaie that's right. the question is, when v-if is false and item is not rendered, it can help the first contentful paint, can't it? cause after all, the time it takes to render element and make it invisible is a wasted time I guess.